# Intellij idea on ubuntu linux doesnt run Application Server Apache tomcat

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, intellij-idea, host

Please save me, when im trying to run localhost server im getting:

> Application Server was not connected before run configuration stop,
>   reason: Unable to ping server at localhost:1099.

And in console:

> /home/devnull/Software/idea-IU-162.2228.15/plugins/apache-tomcat-8.0.38/bin/catalina.sh
>   run Using CATALINA_BASE:
>   /home/devnull/.IntelliJIdea2016.2/system/tomcat/Unnamed_lovelystickers
>   Using CATALINA_HOME:
>   /home/devnull/Software/idea-IU-162.2228.15/plugins/apache-tomcat-8.0.38
>   Using CATALINA_TMPDIR:
>   /home/devnull/Software/idea-IU-162.2228.15/plugins/apache-tomcat-8.0.38/temp
>   Using JRE_HOME: /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64 Using CLASSPATH:
>   /home/devnull/Software/idea-IU-162.2228.15/plugins/apache-tomcat-8.0.38/bin/bootstrap.jar:/home/devnull/Software/idea-IU-162.2228.15/plugins/apache-tomcat-8.0.38/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
>   Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine. Error: A fatal
>   exception has occurred. Program will exit.
>   -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/home/devnull/Software/idea-IU-162.2228.15/plugins/apache-tomcat-8.0.38/endorsed
>   is not supported. Endorsed standards and standalone APIs in modular
>   form will be supported via the concept of upgradeable modules.
>   Disconnected from server

Comment: Check your jdk installation. Also if you pass some specific parameters to it then post them.

Comment: I forgot to say, apache tomcat works fine on eclipse.

Comment: Then compare run string. It comes first in logs in idea and eclipse. Check that they use same jdk and pass same parameters to it. If those lines are different then post them in your question.

Comment: yap, you are right, they are using different jdks

Comment: ive connected in idea jdk same as in eclipse, now i have this (catShroedinger is my pc name): 
Using CLASSPATH:       /home/devnull/Software/idea-IU-162.2228.15/plugins/apache-tomcat-8.0.38/bin/bootstrap.jar:/home/devnull/Software/idea-IU-162.2228.15/plugins/apache-tomcat-8.0.38/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
[2016-10-29 07:27:10,151] Artifact lovelystickers:war: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available.
Error: Exception thrown by the agent : java.net.MalformedURLException: Local host name unknown: java.net.UnknownHostException: catSchroedinger: catSchroedinger: Name or service is unknow.